# Include 'some.php' just pasting in PHP code, no correct preprocessing

Tags: php, nginx, include, fastcgi

I was using Apache before setting up my new website. With Apache the whole code worked well so this is something with **Nginx**. Now I'm using Nginx and there were some difficulties that I got to fix. But now I ran into some trouble.

I created a test.php so you can easily see what's going wrong. In the file there is just:

```
<?php
include 'graph.php';
?>
```

In the **graph.php** there is just some PHP code which usually is need to show some graph stuff. That does not matter. What matters is that this code should never be posted or printed out. When I replace the include statement with just the code that is in the file it works. So why does **include** or even **require_once** not work properly for me?

### Added graph.php code for you

Alright just added the code of the graph.php here:

```
<?php
# set header layout
include 'inc/header.php';

# get parameters year/month of calendar 
$date_d=0;$date_m=0;$date_y=0;
if (isset($_GET['d'])&&isset($_GET['m'])&&isset($_GET['y'])) {
  $date_d = $_GET['d'];
  $date_m = $_GET['m'];
  $date_y = $_GET['y'];
} 
# show diagram of actual statistic overview
echo "<img src='myimage.png' alt='statistic'>";

include 'graph/mycalendar.php';

# set up a date if nothing is set
$actualdate = getdate(time());
if ($month == "")
  $month = $actualdate["mon"];
if ($year == "")
  $year = $actualdate["year"];
# get parameters year/month of calendar 
if (isset($_GET['month'])&&isset($_GET['year'])) {
  $month = $_GET['month'];
  $year = $_GET['year'];
} 

$mycalendar = new MyCalendar;
echo $mycalendar->getMonthView($month, $year);

include 'graph/graph.php';
include 'inc/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `include('graph.php');` or `require_once('graph.php');` instead? I don't know, but maybe Nginx just doesn't work with that 'newer' syntax. Or else maybe `graph.php` has some reference to a 'relative-location' file that would therefore be different for `test.php` and causes it to bug out. Importantly: what is the actual result of `test.php`? A blank page?

Comment: In `graph.php`, try using `<?php` instead of `<?` to start your php code

Comment: If you view source for the link you provided, you see it is printing out the php for a class called calender. Whatever file that is, I bet it's the problem.

Comment: IF you want to have a look into the default file for the server configuration, just let me know.

Comment: @MarkM you were right, I replaced <? with <?php and now the class is not shown anymore. But still not working and strange behaviour. I will check for the other files.

Comment: Alright it works, just the date was wrong. Thank you guys =) I remove the links now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
include 'graph/mycalendar.php';
```

That file stated with

```
<?
```

and with

```
<?php
```

it now works.